# Find differences between current document and previous revision

Tags: couchdb

Is there a way to determine what changes were made in a document? Here's a document and a revision of it

```
{
  "_id": "panel100000",
  "_rev": "1-b4f55d0e03fbfaef0822a0607d5d6ad0",
    "name": "Maya Jambalaya",
    "maritalstatus": "Married",
    "employed": "Full time",
    "education": "College graduate"
  }

{
  "_id": "panel100000",
  "_rev": "2-caab684a341da5185546a028cfb5b0d9",
    "name": "Maya Papaya",
    "maritalstatus": "Married",
    "employed": "Full time",
    "education": "College graduate"
  }
```

In this example, name and maritalstatus have changed. Is there a way to find changes between a document and its previous revisions?

1. Is there anything built-in that does or could track such changes?
2. Is it possible to access a document's revision via a design document?
3. If the answer to #2 is "yes" then does anyone have a template of a design document with which to compare them?

Answer (score 1):

1. No. If you want to track changes, you would probably need to use a data model adapted for that purpose. Otherwise, Couch keeps revisions of the documents and you can query them to manually calculate the diff. Therefore, there are no guarantees that revisions will not be compacted.
2. No. Design documents are built with the latest revision of each documents.
3. ...

If you want to be sure to keep every document changes, you would need to create a document for each change. Those changes could be grouped by a uniqueId and you could use a map/reduce to get the latest value of a document. The diff would need to be made manually tho. The advantage would be that you can easily get the state of the document at a certain time.